# Axios post entire from. (Vue.js)

Tags: vue.js, axios

Is there a way to just post the entire form, instead of having to specify the fields? I thought I had seen it somewhere but can't find it now.

A bit like this in JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    //etc.
});
```

This is in Vue.js component.

Mick

Answer (score 9):

One possible solution is to use `v-model` with object as mentioned by [@MU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44759697/7636961).

Apart from `v-model`, you can also use native [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object, for example when you have dinamically created inputs and you can't/don't want to bind these inputs using `v-model`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    submit: function () {
      const formData = new FormData(this.$refs['form']); // reference to form element
      const data = {}; // need to convert it before using not with XMLHttpRequest
      for (let [key, val] of formData.entries()) {
        Object.assign(data, { [key]: val })
      }
      console.log(data);
      axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', data)
        .then(res => console.log(res.request.response))
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <form ref="form" @submit.prevent="submit">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="number" name="age">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

1. If you are using VueJS you should use `v-model` for all form fields. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html
2. Create in your `data()` object called `form` or something similar and use `v-model='form.fieldName'`
3. Post all together as JSON with `this.axios.post('url', this.form).then(...`

Answer (score 0):

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent="getAllData" id="frm">    
      <input name="input1" placeholder="edit me">
      <input name="input2" placeholder="edit me">
      <input name="input3" placeholder="edit me">
      <input name="input4" placeholder="edit me">
      <input type="submit" >Send</input>
</form>


<script>
   ....
   //your method parts
   methods:{
      getAllData(){
      
         let myForm = document.getElementById('frm'); 
         let formData = new FormData(myForm);
         const data = {}; 
         // need to convert it before using not with XMLHttpRequest
         for (let [key, val] of formData.entries()) {
               Object.assign(data, {[key]: val})
         }
         console.log(data);
       },
    }
   ....
<script>
```